# EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, sigabrt

I get the following crash report from an iPhone:

```
Incident Identifier: 6E2B4585-CB62-422C-B3AC-572865DD3AA7
CrashReporter Key:   c0ee8e4ebe234085fced97effaa20b4466f37166
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:         myApp [3152]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/203530B9-B1BF-48F9-A3D0-B80AE1D53EA4/myApp.app/myApp
Identifier:      myApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-05-30 15:28:52.501 +0200
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.4 (10B350)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  10

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c77e4f8 read + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3450cab0 fileRead + 16
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3450c948 CFReadStreamRead + 336
3   CFNetwork                       0x342983a8 readEntirely(__CFReadStream*, void*, long) + 24
4   CFNetwork                       0x34298188 BinaryCookieStorage::readCookiesFromStream(__CFReadStream*, MemoryCookies*) + 32
5   CFNetwork                       0x34282ecc DiskCookieStorage::readFileToCookies(MemoryCookies*) + 104
6   CFNetwork                       0x342846f6 DiskCookieStorage::syncStorageWithCompletionLocked(unsigned char, void ()() block_pointer) + 2246
7   CFNetwork                       0x3420e54a _CFHTTPCookieStorageFlushCookieStores + 226
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c740bfe __cxa_finalize + 230
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c6eb2d4 exit + 8
10  myApp                   0x000c3fde -[UncaughtExceptionHandler handleException:] (UncaughtExceptionHandler.m:112)
11  Foundation                      0x34eb649c __NSThreadPerformPerform + 456
12  CoreFoundation                  0x345738f4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
13  CoreFoundation                  0x34573158 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
14  CoreFoundation                  0x34571f2a __CFRunLoopRun + 642
15  CoreFoundation                  0x344e5238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
16  CoreFoundation                  0x344e50c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
17  GraphicsServices                0x380c4336 GSEventRunModal + 70
18  UIKit                           0x364012b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
19  myApp                   0x0004b672 main (main.m:16)
20  libdyld.dylib                   0x3c6c6b1c start + 0
...
Thread 10 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c78dd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c6dbad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c6db7f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c6db680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c78dd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c6dbad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c6db7f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c6db680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c78dd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c6dbad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c6db7f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c6db680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 10 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000004    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x07ced000    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x07cecfb0
    r8: 0x00000001    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000170    sp: 0x07cecfac      lr: 0x3c6dbadb      pc: 0x3c78dd98
  cpsr: 0x40000010
```

The problem is it crashes in Thread 10 but I don`t see anything there that can point me on the right direction... (it happens in combination with an phonegap controller)
And I can never reproduce it on simulator, it happens only on device and that very rarely.

Comment: Use **Instruments** and Try to find **Memory Leaks**.

Comment: are you downloading something in background thread?

Comment: its possible that some afnetwork is working in this moment